# Saving a JavaScript based website to html files, keeping format

Tags: javascript, python, html, format

I've searched to the best of my capabilities, haven't found an answer.

I'm trying to save pages like this:
http://www.folkbibeln.it/?book=1joh&chapter=1&verse=1

To separate html pages, and keeping the format. I could take each page, copy, paste in a word processing software and save as html, but it would take hours upon hours. I'm thinking there might be some code I could use to automate it? I just can't figure it out, since it's not acting like a straight up html site.

Python is the language I'm using generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an brute-force approach you could use a [Headless Browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) to load each page for you and save it to a file.

But as mplungjan already mentioned, all texts are in js-files.

You could save these files to your disk, then take the script that builds the html-page and write a little nodejs script that builds all the html-files for you. (Take the original script as a template.)

*But nodejs ain't python*

Depending on what you're trying to do with the texts, it ain't hard to convert these js-files into JSON and parse it, or directly into a python datastructure that you can import and process in some script of your choice.

**Edit:**

On a second Look, I just saw this: http://www.folkbibeln.it/chapters/1joh1.html

There seem to be the files you want as plain html, you just have to download them.

Comment: Thank you. You write:  (Take the original script as a template.) Any idea where I find this?

About your last paragraph, this is what I've tried to do and done. The thing is, the js files are made up of Arrays:

`"function 
get1joh() {
verse = new Array();

verse[0] = new Array('1joh-1-1', 'Det som var frÃ¥n begynnelsen, det vi har hÃ¶rt, det vi med egna Ã¶gon har sett, det vi har skÃ¥dat och rÃ¶rt med vÃ¥ra hÃ¤nder, om detta vittnar vi: Livets Ord.');

And the original text has other words inserted too: "Kapitel 1

Livets Ord 
 Det " etc. That's the formatting I want to keep.

Comment: Wow, that Edit is awesome! How did you find them!? Thank you!

Comment: @AndréNordin Browser Dev-tools (F12)

Answer (score 0):

All the text is in JS files. You load the URL you gave us. Click ctrl-s and choose Web page complete. Then you will have ALL the text in the folder `1 Joh 1 – Svenska Folkbibeln_files` You cannot save as formatted text unless you render the JS in the js files